# Group by into single json colum

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Using SQL I'd like to convert a table that looks like this

| id | col11 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | b |
| 1 | c | d |
| 2 | e | f |
| 2 | g | h |

Into something that looks like this:

| id | combined |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{col1: a, col2:b}, {col1: c, col2:d}] |
| 1 | [{col1: e, col2:f}, {col1: g, col2:h}] |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try to use [`json_build_object`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) function to build a JSON object out of a variadic argument list then use `json_agg` function.

```
SELECT id,
    json_agg(json_build_object('col1',col11,
                               'col2',col2)) combined
FROM t
GROUP BY id
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8b087957a803c355ebf3e577edaeecc3)